# Laravel eloquent insert into select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, insert

I am trying laravel eloquent for sql insert into select query which is as follows-

```
$refId='111';
$newStatus='S2';

INSERT INTO parcel(items, status) SELECT items,'$newStatus' FROM parcel where ref_id ='$refId' LIMIT 1;
```

This query does insertion into ***parcel*** table of my database with the *newStatus* variable where selecting certain items needed from the db. I need to do this using laravel eloquent but can not find any reliable method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to translate your query into Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// First Create Model Parcel and FInd Your required row with id

// Below code use for selecting data from database. 

$parcel = Parcel::query()->where('database column name', '=', $parcel_id)->first()

// If you want to store data in table use below code.

$parcel = new Parcel();
$percel->items = $item;
$percel->status = $newStatus;
$percel->save();
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I was trying to insert the same data from a row of my Parcel table into a new one after just modifying few column values and let the existing values remain same as they were previously. For more clarification I think this may help- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertUsing (since Laravel 5.17).
Your code will be set in only one instruction:

```
DB::table('parcel')->insertUsing(['items', 'status'],
function ($request) use ($newStatus, $refId) {
    $request->select('items', DB::raw("$newStatus"))
        ->from('parcel')
        ->where('ref_id', '=', $refId)
        ->first()
        ->toSql();
});
```